# Python: how to check if shape areas contain points?

Tags: python, shapefile

I have a `shapefile` of Singapore that I visualize in this way:

```
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
### Plot shapefile
sf = shapefile.Reader("myShape.shp")
recs    = sf.records()
shapes  = sf.shapes()
Nshp    = len(shapes)
cns     = []
for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    cns.append(recs[nshp][1])
cns = array(cns)
cm    = get_cmap('Dark2')
cccol = cm(1.*arange(Nshp)/Nshp)
#   -- plot --
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

for nshp in xrange(Nshp):
    ptchs   = []
    pts     = array(shapes[nshp].points)
    prt     = shapes[nshp].parts
    par     = list(prt) + [pts.shape[0]]
    for pij in xrange(len(prt)):
        ptchs.append(Polygon(pts[par[pij]:par[pij+1]]))
        ax.add_collection(PatchCollection(ptchs,facecolor=cccol[nshp,:],edgecolor='k', linewidths=.1))     
ax.set_xlim(103.6,104.1)
ax.set_ylim(1.15,1.48)
```

[image]

Now I have a list of points with coordinates in a `dataframe` and I want to check in which region of the shapefile the points are.

```
mypoints
    lon         lat
0   103.619740  1.280485
1   103.622632  1.268944
2   103.622632  1.274714
3   103.622632  1.277600
4   103.622632  1.280485
```

In particular from the `shapefile` I can extract information of the specific area such as the `name`. In fact, in `recs` I have this information. For instance:

```
recs[0]:

[42,
 1,
 'STRAITS VIEW',
 'SVSZ01',
 'Y',
 'STRAITS VIEW',
 'SV',
 'CENTRAL REGION',
 'CR',
 '21451799CA1AB6EF',
 datetime.date(2016, 5, 11),
 30832.9017,
 28194.0843,
 5277.76082729,
 1127297.23737]
```

In this case `STRAITS VIEW` is the name of the area. At the the end I would like to have a `dataframe` like:

```
mypoints
    lon         lat       name
0   103.619740  1.280485  STRAITS VIEW
1   103.622632  1.268944  STRAITS VIEW
2   103.622632  1.274714  DOWNTOWN
3   103.622632  1.277600  BEDOK
4   103.622632  1.280485  CHANGI
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a coordinate lies inside some Polygon you could use the [Intersects](https://web.archive.org/web/20180723234109/http://www.gdal.org:80/classOGRGeometry.html#aadb34b556c52aef3e93f03cf65d3f4bc) method from GDAL. This method compares two `OGRGeometry` objects and return a boolean value indicating whether they intercept or not.

With this you can iterate over your points, and for each one test if it `Intersects()` with all your Polygon areas. It should look something like:

```
for point_geom in your_points:
    #iterate over your area polygons and check 
    for area_geom in your_areas:
        if area_geom.Intersects(point_geom):
            #then you have a match, save or do as you want
```

**Note:** In case your points are *not* an `OGRGeometry` (your Polygons most probably are as you are reading them from a Shapefile), you can create such Geometry as suggested [here](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html):

```
from osgeo import ogr
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(1198054.34, 648493.09)
```

and in the case of Polygons:

```
ring = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLinearRing)
ring.AddPoint(1179091.1646903288, 712782.8838459781)
ring.AddPoint(1161053.0218226474, 667456.2684348812)
#etc...add all your points, in a loop would be better
# Create polygon
poly = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPolygon)
poly.AddGeometry(ring)
```

Comment: @emax seems that this solved your problem :) glad I could help, remember to Upvote if you found this useful as well. Cheers